# Magento2 Custom Media Image Attribute do not work in Frontend

Tags: magento2

i have a problem by getting a custom image in the frontend.

1. I have a custom media product attribute "image_productlist"
2. In my product import i fill the mediaGallery like this:

`$oTargetProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($aMediaData['overview_image'], ['image_productlist', 'swatch_image'], false, true);
$oTargetProduct->save();`

Where $aMediaData['overview_image'] has the MEDIA IMPORT PATH AND THE FILENAME!

3. After the import i see in my Admin Backend this image in the gallery and the flags 'image_productlist', 'swatch_image' marked at this image.
4. Now i want to get this image with flag: 'image_productlist' in my frontend block.

For this i do something like this:

// get the variant images

```
$existingMediaGalleryEntries = $_simpleProduct->getMediaGalleryEntries();
foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
var_dump($entry->getData());
}
```

I get this list of the images in the gallery but there is no FLAG 'image_productlist'.

What is wrong??

Thanks for help.

Comment: I think that if you want to retrieve a custom image type, you should retrieve product custom attribute directly. I need to do the same stuff. I keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the attribute is setup correctly and that the attribute setting `Used in product listing` is set to `Yes` under Storefront Properties. Then you can get a custom product image attribute by:

```
$imageHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

$attributeImage = $_product->getCustomAttribute('image_productlist');
$attributeImageUrl = $imageHelper->init($_product, 'image_productlist')->setImageFile($attributeImage->getValue())->getUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

On way to achieve it :

Update the **app/design/frontend/{VendorName}/{ThemeName}/etc/view.xml** of your theme :

```
    <image id="product_custom_image" type="image_productlist">
        <width>265</width>
        <height>265</height>
    </image>
```

You need to update the default configuration file **view.xsd** as described in this post with a plugin: [Extending the complexType named "imageType" with a custom image type](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102498/extending-the-complextype-named-imagetype-with-a-custom-image-type)

Then use the default image helper function in order to retrieve your image type such as :

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory
 */
protected $helperFactory;

$image = $this->helperFactory->create()->init($product, 'product_custom_image')
            ->constrainOnly(true)
            ->keepAspectRatio(true)
            ->keepTransparency(true)
            ->keepFrame(false)
            ->resize(200, 300);

$imageUrl = $image->getUrl();
```