# Magento 2.3.1 override view.xsd Using Plugin Not working before 2.3.1 it's Working

Tags: overrides, image, magento2.3.1

I am trying to override view.xsd using Plugin and it's working on magento 2.1.x and 2.2.x but not working in 2.3.1.

I Add Same code To describe Here.

[Extending the complexType named "imageType" with a custom image type](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102498/extending-the-complextype-named-imagetype-with-a-custom-image-type)

Comment: Can you post what you've tried, and also try the new code I've updated getSchema @Pratik

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran Just try to override SchemaLocator Using preference and plugin in both case it's not working in 2.3.1

Comment: Is that the overridden class works? Add a log to it and verify before going further

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran I have much experience in magento so I try everything before post here including log.

Comment: you must be finding it where it fails and where it went wrong. Is there any error while compilation or what that does give after been applied rewrite or interceptors

Answer (score 2):

Try this, you can extend using **preference**

Add di.xml in the below folder

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

then add the below code to it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Config\SchemaLocator" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Config\SchemaLocator" />
</config>
```

then add **SchemaLocator.php** in the below path

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Config/SchemaLocator.php

then add the below code to it

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Config;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Dir;

class SchemaLocator extends \Magento\Framework\Config\SchemaLocator implements \Magento\Framework\Config\SchemaLocatorInterface
{
   protected $schema = null;
   /**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader $moduleReader
 */
public function getSchema()
{
    $result = sprintf(realpath(__DIR__ . '/../etc/view.xsd'));
    return $result;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getPerFileSchema()
{
    return $this->_schema;
}
}
```

the above code will change the path of **view.xsd** to your custom module from core.

Finally, add the **view.xsd** in the below path

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/view.xsd

then you can add you changes there.

NOTE : This is working example in M2.3 and in previous version used **plugin** instead of **preference**

Comment: Hello @Prathap Have you check link i post in Question ? You Post same Answer which I Add in Link and it's not working in 2.3.1

Comment: Hey @Pratik Just give it a try and I don't think any of those answer using preference and this is working fine in M2.3. I've tested.

Comment: Have You check in 2.3.0 or 2.3.1 ?

Comment: Is it working or not?? not much diff from 2.3 to 2.3.1 in regards of di

Comment: it's not working in 2.3.1.